# What exactly is an std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it a real hardware thread?

I have a program which reads data from 30 COM devices every second and so far I only have access to 7. It works great when I implemented multithreading, one thread for each device and it doesn't block off my GUI while it waits to read data (it takes 30ms). I'm wondering though what will happen if I exceed the amount of threads I have on my CPU? If this isn't possible how would I approach this?

Comment: What do you mean _real hardware thread_?? Multithreading is a software feature most and foremost.

Comment: ***I'm wondering though what will happen if I exceed the amount of threads I have on my CPU?*** It would likely be fine. No this is not a real hardware thread. Your OS will schedule which threads will be executing on what CPU cores. Your OS most likely will have 100s of threads executing even though your CPU only has 16 threads.

Comment: This may help however I did not spend minutes to review:  [https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~pandey/Teaching/ECS150/Lects/05scheduling.pdf](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~pandey/Teaching/ECS150/Lects/05scheduling.pdf)

Comment: These COM devices are what? serial ports?

Comment: @Surt yeah, serial ports

Comment: 30  threads making, (mostly), blocking reads from COM ports is nothing.  It is just not a problem at all, even on a single-core processor from 20 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

`std::thread` is not a "hardware thread". `std::thread` is a class in the C++ standard library. Instance of the `std::thread` class is an object that acts as a RAII container for a "native thread" i.e. a thread of execution provided by the API of the operating system.

When you create a `std::thread` (assuming you don't use the default constructor), the constructor will use the operating system API to create a native thread, and calls the passed function.

> I'm wondering though what will happen if I exceed the amount of threads I have on my CPU?

The operating system has a subsystem called "process scheduler" which allocates the time of the hardware CPU cores (or logical core in case of hyper threading, which I assume is what you mean by "hardware thread") time for each of the threads running on the system. The number of (logical) cores the CPUs of the system has affects how many threads can be executed in parallel, but doesn't limit how many threads the operating system can manage.

As such, nothing in particular will happen or will stop happening. If your system has more threads ready to run than number of (logical) CPU cores, then the operating system will not be able to give CPU time to all of the threads in parallel.

Note that creating native threads has a performance penalty, and having more threads waiting to run (excluding those waiting for disk or network) than the number of cores to execute them will reduce the performance of the system.

Comment: I don't think you have the same definition of "hardware thread" as the OP. It looks like they mean "physical threads of execution", i.e. (virtual in case of hyperthreading) cores. And `std::thread` doesn't represent that.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I edited correspondingly

Comment: Is std::thread really an RAII container? When it goes out of scope instead of detaching or joining in the destructor, it calls std::terminate and ends the whole program, which I would argue is against RAII principles.

Answer (score 4):

`std::thread` represents a thread, managed by the operating system. It has its stack, registers, instruction pointer etc. However, it is still managed by the OS. The operating system handles all the scheduling, assigning the thread to the hardware core and then preempting it if necessary to do another work on that core.

In a regular program you can't really lock core to do your work without any OS intervention. Otherwise, it could have negative impact on the stability of the system.

---

If you launch more threads than there are cores on your CPU, and they all *run all the time*, the OS will start swapping them in and out, effectively keeping them all running. However, this swapping is not for free, and you can slow everything down if you have too many of them.

However, if your threads are halted for whatever reason -- for example, you threads stop on a mutex, wait on a condition variable, or simply goes to sleep (e.g. via `std::this_thread::sleep_for`), then it no longer consume the hardware resources during that wait. In that scenario it is perfectly fine to have much more threads than there are cores on your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm wondering though what will happen if I exceed the amount of threads I have on my CPU?**

You might experience a lot of (unneeded) task switching, each taking 1us to 22ms depending on what exactly ran before.

Depending on your OS or setup you can get the serial ports to do a lot of work for you. Also the amount of actual work on the individual receiving COM port matters.

- OS sends a message that there are some data you can read from a given buffer.
- OS wakes your thread as there is something to read on the port
- Interrupt, wakes the thread and returns

In all cases a single thread might be able to handle all 30 COM's as most of the time is waiting for the very slow serial ports to send the data.

Most serial ports are buffered and only need to be emptied after several chars have been received. Some serial cards have DMA so you don't even need to empty it yourself.